# how to find highest price during period using "GOOGLEFINANCE"

Tags: spreadsheet

I'm try to find highest price using GoogleFinance.

=IF($I5="KRX", GOOGLEFINANCE("KRX:" & $J5, "price"), IF($I5="KOSDAQ", GOOGLEFINANCE("KOSDAQ:" & $J5, "price"), ""))

This is the formula what I used to find current price of stock.

I have data in 2 cells

B3 = 2023.Sep.1

C4 = 2023.Oct.2

I tried using the keyword "High", but it showed me all the high prices within the period I entered, but I only want to find the highest price within a certain period.

Thank you